# Strange result in deducting from a Decimal number Truncated or Floored version of the same

Tags: c#, rounding, truncate, decimal-point, floor

Upon trying in simple Console App, with a code like the following, the result found to be quite something unexpected as per the clip following in the end.
Code Used

```
double A = 1234567.8991;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A - Math.Truncate(A)));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(A - Math.Floor(A)));
```

Any reason for the said *0.8991000000**38743*** appearing so as follows?

[image]

Since, it was only 0.8991, that was expected!

Comment: "Decimal number" has a very specific meaning in C# or .NET, and what you have are NOT decimal numbers, but floating-point binary.  You can't store 1234567.8991 exactly using floating-point, so the compiler gives you the closest value that can be represented. Try again with `decimal A = 1234567.8991m;`

Comment: Sorry Ben! But Decimal, although a good suggestion, is found to be not capable of storing gigantic numbers required by Banking Companies. Any other type of data variable? However, if I do round the main Double Data Type input to only 10 digits would that be satisfactorily reliable?
Thanks again dear!

Comment: What kind of gigantic numbers are "Banking Companies" trying to store?  But I'm not saying you need to use Decimal, but that if your code uses floating-point, your question and title should say floating-point, not Decimal.  Also, the precision of a floating-point number varies based on its magnitude, if you are passing in "gigantic" numbers too large for Decimal, then you will also not be happy with the results of `A - floor(A)`